# Error setting work_mem for postgres instance running on aws lightsail via pgAdmin and aws cli

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-lightsail

I am attempting to run this command to update the work_mem on my lightsail postgres instance.

aws lightsail update-relational-database-parameters --relational-database-name *mydb* --parameters "parameterName=work_mem,parameterValue=16MB,applyMethod=immediate"

I get the error that 16MB is an invalid parameter value.  Is work_mem not available to be set?  Is this just a syntax issue?  I tried to update the setting via pgadmin but my user does not the appropriate privileges so I went down the aws cli path and I am getting this opaque error without any suggestion of why the value is invalid.  Any help would be much appreciated for people who have run into this issue before.  The default of 4MB for work_mem is not sufficient and I'm wondering if I need to migrate to RDS in order to have admin privileges to manage db settings.  Is this a downside to lightsail?

Comment: Could you show us the real and complete error, not your interpretation? SET work_mem TO '16MB'; should work fine.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, sure.  Thanks.  


$ aws lightsail update-relational-database-parameters --relational-database-name mydb --parameters "parameterName=work_mem,parameterValue=8MB,applyMethod=immediate"

An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the UpdateRelationalDatabaseParameters operation: invalid parameter value: 8MB

Comment: What's the result when you try to get the available parameters? aws lightsail get-relational-database-parameters --relational-database-name mydb